# How to write a GET query in the Strongloop front end

Tags: json, node.js, strongloop, loopback

I want to check data using the strongloop api. I have everything set up and working, but i do not want to write C# just to check for an update to a datamodel, for now. I want to use the provided front end. i.e. using the GET function.

Lets say I have a table A with columns: A1,A2 and A3.

How do i get the value for a row in A, such that A1=5? 
What is the syntax and semantics? I want to learn how it is used and not just remember it.

Comment: By strongloop you mean loopback ?

Comment: Yes. The API explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter instances to match a property with a given value, using the [where filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter)

Let's say you have a model `Foo` with property `bar` of type number, and you want to get all instances of `Foo` with `bar` = 5.

Using the API explorer, make a `GET Foo\` and in the filter field  write the filter just like you would in a JSON file : `{"where": {"bar": 5}}`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i needed.